# Linux kernel conflicts

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

```
 rpm --query --all '*kernel*'
 kernel-headers-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64
 kernel-firmware-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.noarch
 dracut-kernel-004-256.el6.noarch
 kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64
 abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.4-14.el6.centos.x86_64
 kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64
 libreport-plugin-kerneloops-2.0.5-20.el6.x86_64

 uname -r
 2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64

 /etc/init.d/network restart 
 Shutting down loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
 WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/noipv6, it will be ignored in a future release.
 FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or      directory
```

Eth0 does not attain a given IP
If i do ifconfig eht0 up and down it says device does not exist.
if i do network restart , output is pasted above?

Is there some conflict between 2 packages ? How can I solve ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've uninstalled your `kernel-2.6.32-220.4.1.el6` RPM *while* running that kernel. This may have happened as part of a kernel RPM upgrade (although usually, kernel "upgrades" are treated as installs and won't remove existing kernels).

Check your `grub.conf` file and make sure that an installed kernel is set as the boot kernel. Then, reboot the system. The currently installed kernel is `kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6`. Alternatively, download the `kernel-2.6.32-220.4.1.el6` RPM and install it to get the directory and binaries back.

Comment: thnanks for a reply @hrunting...  

grub is configured for kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6... and 

installing kernel-2.6.32-220.4.1.el6 rpm gives error saying   
package kernel-2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 (which is newer than kernel-2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64) is already installed

Comment: You can force installation of the older kernel with `rpm --force` (not sure exactly how with `yum`, but it's probably similar).

Comment: yeah i read that .. just scared that I may make the machine not bootable at all ..

Comment: forcinf the kernel install did it .. Thanks a ton ..

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, you seem to have managed to delete the package of the running kernel. Find out how that happened, and note so it doesn't happen again.

`yum` is set up to keep several kernels around, by default 3. Check `/etc/yum.conf`, particularly `installonly_limit=3`. Don't mess with that! It is critical to have older kernels around in case the system refuses to boot after an update, or some update fails. `yum` has failsafes so the running kernel isn't removed, so this shouldn't happen.

If a package gets broken/erased, you can fix that with `yum reinstall <package>`. To do a `rpm --force` is a desperate measure, to be used only under duress (and knowing exactly what you are doing). It almost guarantees (part of) the system gets broken.